# Python - Export large Dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export

I am trying to export a large dataframe df (100K lines by 100 columns) to CSV as fast as possible.

df contains columns of different datatype, but each row for a given column is of the same datatype.

Using pandas' "to_csv" requires around 190 seconds

```
import pandas as pd

df.to_csv(PathEXPORT,index=None)
```

In comparison, changing the dataframe to a list of lists and using csv.writer takes approx. 180 sec.

```
list_df = df.values.tolist()

import csv

with open(PathEXPORT, "w", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerows(list_df)
```

Do you have any suggestions to increase the exportation speed to CSV?

Thank you very much